# Highlight a period in graph with R

Tags: r, graph, performanceanalytics

Is there an easy way to highlight the period in R?

Right now I am trying to use the following, but it does not work for me:

```
library (PerformanceAnalytics)
period <- c("2018-02/2019-01")
chart.TimeSeries(btc_xts, 
                 period.areas = "2018-02/2019-01",
                 period.color = "lightgrey")
```

As a result, I see the historical graph, but I do not the the highlighting.

The outcome attached. Who could help?

Thank you!

[the result of the action, no highlighting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6zUp.png)

Answer (score 1):

I've never used the library but reading from the doc of period.areas :

> period.areas : these are shaded areas described by start and end dates in a vector of
> xts date rangees, e.g., c("1926-10::1927-11","1929-08::1933-03")

The code should be :

```
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
period = c("2018-02::2019-01")
chart.TimeSeries(btc_xts, 
                 period.areas = period,
                 period.color = "lightgrey")
```

`

Comment: Sorry, does not work for me. I just see a bold graph after using your or mine method.

Comment: Maybe somebody knows why do I receive a bold graph in both cases?